# How to OrderBy an item of a list?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, controller, repository

I want to discovery how can I order by an item of a list!
When I try to order by it doesn't work...I don't know what I have to do! Check the images down...

[There is my list who I want to order by 1 to 12, these numbers are my rates that are in the NumeroTaxas column within my list TaxaBandeiraAdministratoras](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kr5s.png)

```js
        public BandeiraAdministradora ObterPorId(Guid id, bool readOnly)
        {
           BandeiraAdministradora bandeiraAdministradora = null;

            bandeiraAdministradora = Db.BandeiraAdministradora.AsNoTracking()
                                     .Include(x => x.Administradora)
                                     .Include(x => x.Bandeira)
                                     .Include(x => x.TaxaBandeiraAdministradoras)
                                     .Where(x => x.BandeiraAdministradoraId == id)
                                     .FirstOrDefault();

            return bandeiraAdministradora;
        }
```

```js
        public BandeiraAdministradora ObterPorId(Guid id, bool readOnly)
        {
           BandeiraAdministradora bandeiraAdministradora = null;

            bandeiraAdministradora = Db.BandeiraAdministradora.AsNoTracking()
                                     .Include(x => x.Administradora)
                                     .Include(x => x.Bandeira)
                                     .Include(x => x.TaxaBandeiraAdministradoras)
                                     .Where(x => x.BandeiraAdministradoraId == id)
                                     .OrderBy(x => x.TaxaBandeiraAdministradoras.Where(t => t.NumeroTaxas))
                                     .FirstOrDefault();
            return bandeiraAdministradora;
        }
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code, post the *actual code* so people can copy/paste to create an answer.

Comment: Ok, I will edit my post!

Comment: Can you help me now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really simple. If you want to order a list of people by their age, for example, you just do it(don't forget of put the using System.LINQ statement):

```
List<Person> orderedPeople = unorderedPeople.OrderBy((p) => p.Age).ToList();
```

Comment: But the problem is that I need to orderBy in my query, and I don't know how I'm do that...right I try to do what you sugest but now I don't know where I'm put this ordened list in my query

Comment: Additional information: DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable.

Comment: I use like this .OrderBy(x => x.TaxaBandeiraAdministradoras.OrderBy((t) => t.NumeroTaxas).ToList())

Comment: Just a question... Why are you ordering it two times?

Comment: And if did it solve your problem, please mark it as answer